# JQplot dynamic data

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jqplot

Using: JQPlot, JavaScript, Asp.net 4.5, C# and MS Visual Studio 2012.

Hi guys Here's some code I'm having an issue with:

```
script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataArray = [];

    <%foreach(Last12MonthsRegistered reg in dbregistered)
                  {%>
    dataArray.push(['<%=reg.MonthName.Trim()%>',<%= reg.TotalReg%>]);
        <%}%>

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [dataArray], {
        // Give the plot a title.
        title: 'Users Registered Last 12 Months',
        axesDefaults: {
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        },
        axes: {
            // options for each axis are specified in seperate option objects.
            xaxis: {
                label: "Months"
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: "User Total"
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see I'm trying to render a jqplot graph using data i obtain from my SQL Database, this data is bound to a list of objects.
I access the values and loop through a Foreach loop in the script above to populate an array, which in turn is used for the JQplot.

Problem i have is nothing shows, when i stepped through the JS script its showed me the following results:

```
dataArray.push(['October',0]);

dataArray.push(['November',0]);

dataArray.push(['December',0]);

dataArray.push(['January',1]);

dataArray.push(['February',8]);

dataArray.push(['March',4]);

dataArray.push(['April',1]);

dataArray.push(['May',0]);

dataArray.push(['June',0]);

dataArray.push(['July',1]);

dataArray.push(['August',1]);

dataArray.push(['September',1]);
```

which looks correct?  but then hovering over the array while debugging it shows:

```
0: Array[2]
1: Array[2]
2: Array[2]
3: Array[2]
4: Array[2]
5: Array[2]
6: Array[2]
7: Array[2]
8: Array[2]
9: Array[2]
10: Array[2]
11: Array[2]
length: 12
__proto__: Array[0]
```

which doesn't look correct at all!
As you probably guessed when I continue I get a blank graph.

Yes I am fairly new to JavaScript, and This is my first time using JQPlot, I'm struggling to find the information i need in there documentation, so I'm hoping you guys can tell me why my array appears to be wrong.

Cheers guys/girls

**UPDATE: 24/10/2013 - 11:24 AM**
found some more info and changed my code to a bar chart.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var dataArray = [];
    var ticks = [];

    <%foreach(Last12MonthsRegistered reg in dbregistered)
                  {%>
    dataArray.push(<%= reg.TotalReg%>);
    <%}%>

    <%foreach(Last12MonthsRegistered reg in dbregistered)
                  {%>
    ticks.push('<%= reg.MonthName.Trim()%>');
    <%}%>

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [dataArray], {
        // Give the plot a title.

        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true }
        },
        // Custom labels for the series are specified with the "label"
        // option on the series option.  Here a series option object
        // is specified for each series.
        series: [
            { label: 'Users Registered' },
        ],
        // Show the legend and put it outside the grid, but inside the
        // plot container, shrinking the grid to accomodate the legend.
        // A value of "outside" would not shrink the grid and allow
        // the legend to overflow the container.
        legend: {
            show: true,
            placement: 'outsideGrid'
        },
        axes: {
            // options for each axis are specified in seperate option objects.
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxsisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            },
            yaxis: {
                pad: 1.05
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Seems the arrays are fine, and i am getting the month names on the x axsis which is great.....Only problem is there stacked on each other to the very left, so nothing gets displayed and the names are over each other.....

im baffled, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code started working as soon as i corrected the `$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer` spelling.
[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/uCq97/1/)

```
    <%foreach(Last12MonthsRegistered reg in dbregistered)
    {%>
       dataArray.push(['<%=reg.MonthName.Trim()%>',<%= reg.TotalReg%>]);
    <%}%>

    <%foreach(Last12MonthsRegistered reg in dbregistered)
    {%>
       ticks.push('<%= reg.MonthName.Trim()%>');
    <%}%>

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [dataArray], {
                // Give the plot a title.

                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true }
                },
                // Custom labels for the series are specified with the "label"
                // option on the series option.  Here a series option object
                // is specified for each series.
                series: [
                    { label: 'Users Registered' },
                ],
                // Show the legend and put it outside the grid, but inside the
                // plot container, shrinking the grid to accomodate the legend.
                // A value of "outside" would not shrink the grid and allow
                // the legend to overflow the container.
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    placement: 'outsideGrid'
                },
                axes: {
                    // options for each axis are specified in seperate option objects.
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                        ,ticks: ticks
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        pad: 1.05,
                        min: 0
                    }
                }
    });
```